# how to to show a Web page in my WebView, offline, that contains JavaScript codes

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, panorama-control

I can not speak english correctly, excuse me...

I want to show a Web page in my WebView, offline, But this is not a normal web page.

because, This page contains JavaScript codes to view the panoramic photos.

After I saved this page, then, I click on it, But there is nothing to display me.

Why???

How can I to show this Web page in my WebView, offline.

Help Me Please....

[it is my Target Web Site](http://www.imamali.net/vtour/)

[image]

Comment: Do remember that if you're trying to load offline you'll need ALL of the resources this page uses, js, images, css etc.

Comment: Are you sure that you can view it offline in normal browser?

Comment: no, i can not view it offline in normal browser. how do i do?

Comment: your page offline php or html? because in webview asset cannot load js,css,or another file with php page. and can load with html page

Comment: please check this for sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753726

Answer (score 0):

Create **assets** folder in your project and put your webpage in assets folder.

Use following code to display offline webpage from assets folder.

```
    WebView wView;  
    wView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
    wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourhtmlpagename.html");
```

Comment: The problem is that when I save this, there is nothing to display me. how to save this web page with all javaScript codes to show in my WebView