# Why does my CSS and PHP include not load in my WebView

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, webview

I use a `WebView` in my app. When the app is not connected to the internet I want to serve the site locally. I was able to build the `APK` and install the app onto my device, but when I start the app offline, it is just showing the body `PHP`, but it did not call/load the `CSS` File or include the `PHP` files.

Directory structure in Android Studio :

[image]

This is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nointernet.php");
        }
    }
```

This is my "No Internet" page

```
<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <?php include 'assets\inc\navmobpage.php';  ?>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container" align="center" style="background-color: white;padding-top: 50px;">
    <img src="assets\img\nointernet.png" width="100%" />
    <a class="btref" href="http://xx.xx.xx">REFRESH</a>
  </div>

  <?php include 'assets\inc\footmob.php';   ?>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="assets\general\jquery\jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets\general\bootstrap\js\bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  </body>
```

Comment: Where are you loading the css?

Comment: WebView (same as any other browser) can't run PHP. You either have to run a PHP server on your device, or load those files from server.

Comment: Oh okay, i try to replace with html @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not ship with a `PHP` server. Therefore for all common intents and purposes, it is not possible to serve a `.php` file locally.

You would need to rewrite your offline page to function without any `PHP` code.

I assume the `CSS` you refer to is also part of the `PHP` include and therefore is not loading for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks, the first answer from @VladyslavMatviienko successfull for me